# Javascript horizontal slider not working

Tags: plugins, jquery, javascript

I'm using an old version of the Slidedeck Plugin (v.1.4.5) and I have a javascript problem with one of the skins I'm using. More precisely, the horizontal slides are stitched together and I can't figure out how to fix this. I want each slide to be independent, without any content from the next or previous slide to be seen on the active slide.

You can see in the screenshot from below that the middle slide has visible content from the previous and next slide, which obviously I don't want to be visible.

[image]

I should mention that I have very limited knowledge of javascript / jQuery, and I suspect it's a js problem because the CSS is the same for all skins - the only variable is the script used by each skin.

You can see the slider behavior on [this website](http://kiduniya.com/) and below is the full script used for the slider skin. I would appreciate any help on this. To change the slides click on each slide arrow from left or right side, or you can use the directional keys on the keyboard.

```
(function($){
SlideDeckSkin['fullwidth-sexy'] = function(slidedeck){
    var ns = 'fullwidth-sexy';
    var elems = {};
        elems.slidedeck = $(slidedeck);
        elems.frame = elems.slidedeck.closest('.skin-' + ns);

    // Disable spines as this skin is not meant to function with spines on
    elems.slidedeck.slidedeck().setOption('hideSpines', true);

    elems.frame.append('<a href="#prev" class="sd-' + ns + '-nav prev">Previous</a><a href="#next" class="sd-' + ns + '-nav next">Next</a>');
    elems.slidedeck.append('<div class="' + ns + '-mask left"></div><div class="' + ns + '-mask right"></div>');

    elems.frame.find('.sd-' + ns + '-nav').bind('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        elems.slidedeck.slidedeck().options.pauseAutoPlay = true;
        if($this.hasClass('prev')){
            elems.slidedeck.slidedeck().prev();
        } else {
            elems.slidedeck.slidedeck().next();
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.skin-fullwidth-sexy .slidedeck').each(function(){
        if(typeof($.data(this, 'skin-fullwidth-sexy')) == 'undefined' || $.data(this, 'skin-fullwidth-sexy') == null){
            $.data(this, 'skin-fullwidth-sexy', new SlideDeckSkin['fullwidth-sexy'](this));
        }
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You only have one slider on your example -- do you have an example with two?

Comment: There are three slides, I've just disabled the auto-slide to better debug with firebug. You can navigate between them using the directional keys or the left/right arrows on each slide.

Comment: The extra visible items has to do with the CSS not the javascript.

Comment: It gets worse as you make the screen bigger -- I see two on my screen.

Comment: I noticed while making the screenshot the same problem. I'll go back to the CSS then. I was sure that it has something to do with javascript because the CSS is the same for all skins and another one without arrows works just fine but it doesn't have the navigational arrows which I need.

Comment: I managed to figure it out. It was indeed the CSS. I've changed the `width` value from 100% to 900px which is the value I need. I've also added proper `height` and `margin` - now everything is ok. Thanks anyway for your help and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: No problem glad to hear it is solved.

Answer (score 1):

The following might work, but it is hard to test without an example of what you are trying to do.

What I did is added a unique number to the `ns` variable (for namespace I assume.)  This number is passed to the callback of the each function.  ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/))

```
(function($){
SlideDeckSkin['fullwidth-sexy'] = function(slidedeck,uniqueName){
    var ns = 'fullwidth-sexy'+uniqueName;
    var elems = {};
        elems.slidedeck = $(slidedeck);
        elems.frame = elems.slidedeck.closest('.skin-' + ns);

    // Disable spines as this skin is not meant to function with spines on
    elems.slidedeck.slidedeck().setOption('hideSpines', true);

    elems.frame.append('<a href="#prev" class="sd-' + ns + '-nav prev">Previous</a><a href="#next" class="sd-' + ns + '-nav next">Next</a>');
    elems.slidedeck.append('<div class="' + ns + '-mask left"></div><div class="' + ns + '-mask right"></div>');

    elems.frame.find('.sd-' + ns + '-nav').bind('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        elems.slidedeck.slidedeck().options.pauseAutoPlay = true;
        if($this.hasClass('prev')){
            elems.slidedeck.slidedeck().prev();
        } else {
            elems.slidedeck.slidedeck().next();
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.skin-fullwidth-sexy .slidedeck').each(function(n){
        if(typeof($.data(this, 'skin-fullwidth-sexy')) == 'undefined' || $.data(this, 'skin-fullwidth-sexy') == null){
            $.data(this, 'skin-fullwidth-sexy', new SlideDeckSkin['fullwidth-sexy'+n](this,n));
        }
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I've added an screenshot in the original post which clearly shows the problem with the slides. I've also tried the updated script you posted but everything is the same.